# Extracting rows from a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a n by m `data.frame` where column 1 has the information of interest. I want to create sub `data.frame`s based upon what the value in a row of column 1 is.

Example:

```
P Cat  Q    S... nth Column
S data data data data 
S ...       ...       
A ...
I ...
. ...
. ...
. ...
mth row
```

Now what I want to do is create a `data.frame` where column P has a value of S, then one for A...,etc.

I have been unsuccessfully trying things such as:

```
s <- data.frame(df1$P = S)
s <- data.frame(df1$P [,:5]) <- #In this case the data I want stops at row 5
```

I would like to end up with something like

```
s = P Data1 Data2 Data3 Data nth
    S
    S
    ...
    S
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
s <- data.frame(df1$P = S)
```

try:

```
s <- data.frame(df1[df1$P == S,])
```

or

```
s <- data.frame(df1[df1$P == 'S',])
```

if you want to control number of rows try:

```
s <- data.frame(df1[df1$P == 'S',1:5])
```

Comment: Many thanks, the third one is the one I wanted and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to wrap all these selections in `data.frame(...)` - the results will be a `data.frame` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking your data into a `list` of `data.frames` using `split` may also work here, and prevent cluttering your workspace. E.g:

```
df1 <- data.frame(P=c("S","S","A","I"),data=rep(1,4))
df1

#  P data
#1 S    1
#2 S    1
#3 A    1
#4 I    1

result <- split(df1,df1$P)

#$A
#  P data
#3 A    1
#
#$I
#  P data
#4 I    1
#
#$S
#  P data
#1 S    1
#2 S    1
```

You can then access the parts of the list like:

```
result$S
```

or

```
result[["S"]]
```

Voila:

```
#  P data
#1 S    1
#2 S    1
```